# Don't want to pollute an object's prototype. How to have prototype inheritance w/ namespace?

Tags: javascript

I don't want to pollute the prototype of objects with all my library's methods. I want to hide them inside a __namespace property.

---

When you try to access an object property, if it is undefined, it will look up the prototype chain like so

```
a.c -> a.prototype.c -> a.prototype.prototype.c ..
```

I would like to achieve

```
a.__namespace.c -> a.prototype.__namespace.c, a.prototype.prototype.__namespace.c ...
```

Exemple :

```
function A(){};
A.prototype.__namespace = {};
A.prototype.c = 2; // normal 
A.prototype.__namespace.c = 2; // inside namespace

var a = new A();
a.__namespace = {};
console.log(a.c) // prints 2
console.log(a.__namespace.c); //undefined. Would like to print 2.
```

Is there a javascript functionality that allows this **other** than creating it like :

```
function NameSpace(){}
NameSpace.prototype.c = 3;

var a = new A();
a.__namespace = new NameSpace();
console.log(a.__namespace);
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxggshys/).

Comment: you are overwriting value of namespace by initializing a.namespace={}

Comment: Exactly. That's the point.

Comment: If you want parents value you need not to do a.namespace= {}

Comment: It overwrite the value of namespace.b by using a.namespace.b=3

Comment: I am asking if there is a way that if a.__namespace.c is undefined on the instance, that it will look up the prototype chain

Comment: Just like if you write a.c, if a.c is undefined, it will look for a.prototype.c, a.prototype.prototype.c ... Now, I want a.__namespace.c, a.prototype.__namespace.c, a.prototype.prototype.__namespace.c, a.prototype.prototype.__namespace.c

Comment: You're looking for `a.__namespace = Object.create(A.prototype.__namespace);`

Comment: If you remove line a.__namespace = {}; then it will print 2.

Comment: @Bergi yup I think that's it

Comment: @SundarSingh I think you did not understand the question.. I want to be able to redefine properties on the instance also.

Comment: Remove `a.__namespace = {};` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just [Fiddled](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/u731v62h/2/) around and came up with that. I'm not 100% sure if it's what you are intending.

Essentially I am storing the `prototyped` functions in a single property of the `prototype`.

```
SomeObject.prototype.someNamespace = Object.create(SomeOtherObject.prototype);
```

Of course, the `SomeOtherObject` will have to have a *polluted* prototype.

**ATTEMPT 2**

I tried [again](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/5kpf2heL/6/). Is this what you are intending?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not it. Check the updated question.